# Airflow CLI Trigger_dag suppress warning

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to triggering the Airflow DAG from CLI, DAG is trigger fine, but am getting bunch of python warning messages, can anyone help me, how to suppress those warning messages.

Command: `airflow trigger_dag -e 2021-07-13 Test_CI_DAG`

logs:

```
/var/xxx/airflow/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py:65: PendingDeprecationWarning:
Invalid arguments were passed to SSHOperator (task_id: run_spark_job).
Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0.
 Invalid arguments were: *args: () **kwargs: {'xcom_push': True}
  super(SSHOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
/var/xxx/airflow/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py:88: PendingDeprecationWarning: 
Invalid arguments were passed to PythonOperator (task_id: push_values). Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0.
Invalid arguments were:
*args: ()
**kwargs: {'xcom_push': True}
  super(PythonOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
/var/xxx/airflow/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py:88: PendingDeprecationWarning: 
Invalid arguments were passed to PythonOperator (task_id: pull_values). Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0.
 Invalid arguments were:
*args: ()
**kwargs: {'xcom_push': True}
  super(PythonOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
/var/xxx/airflow/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py:65: PendingDeprecationWarning: 
Invalid arguments were passed to SSHOperator (task_id: price_promotion_broad). 
Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
```

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are related to the arguments you are passing to the operators. For example [SSHOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator/index.html#module-airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator) and `PythonOperator` both expect `do_xcom_push` and you are using `xcom_push`.
I can't tell if there are other warning since the logs are not complete.

Anyway, consider upgrading the Airflow version you are running to 2.0.0, checkout the [official guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.1/upgrading-to-2.html) and docs on how to do it.